# Iterate over Java class hierarchy using functional programming

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, functional-programming

Considering this piece of Kotlin code, that collects all declared fields in superclass hierarchy, is there way to write it using functional programming?

```kotlin
var scanClass: Class<*>? = someClass

val fields = mutableListOf<Field>()
while (scanClass != null) {
    fields += scanClass.declaredFields
    scanClass = scanClass.superclass
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can write the same code using functional programming in Kotlin by using a sequence of classes generated by iteratively taking the superclass of the current class. Here's an example:

```
val fields = generateSequence(someClass) { it.superclass }
.flatMap { it.declaredFields.asSequence() }
.toList()
```

In this code, the generateSequence function generates a sequence of classes, starting with someClass and then iteratively taking its superclass. The flatMap function is used to flatten the sequence of arrays of fields into a single sequence of fields. Finally, the toList function collects the elements of the sequence into a list.

Comment: Thanks, I found that concept of generateSequence is described here in easier words: [https://kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html)

Comment: It looks to be equivalent of [Flux.expand](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#expand-java.util.function.Function-) that I wasn'able to find earlier